# How to start and manage a process in busybox inittab, and rcS as early as possible?

Tags: linux, busybox, sysvinit, busybox-init

I am working on an embedded Linux system where busybox is being used as init.
I have 2 requirements on running my application.

1. My application needs to start as early as possible;
2. It needs to be managed by busybox (respawn if it exits).

Firstly, I started my application in /etc/inittab as follows,

```
# now run any rc scripts
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# Put a getty on the serial port
#ttyS3::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  ttyS3 57600 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
#no login
::respawn:/usr/bin/myapp
::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

In this way myapp is managed by busybox, when it exits, busybox will start it automatically.

But I found lots of services/daemons are started by `/etc/init.d/rcS` before starting myapp.
this does NOT meet the 1st requirement.

I created `/etc/init.d/S02myapp`(which is started by `/etc/init.d/rcS`) to start my application in it, but it does not meet the 2nd requirement (I don't know if it is possible for busybox to manage the application started by `rcS`).

Then I got another way to meet both requirements as follows,

1. Change `/etc/init.d/S02myapp`, to start another `myapp.sh` as a background process.
2. Create `myapp.sh`, where it has a while-loop, in which myapp is started as foreground process.

With it myapp is started as early as possible (launched by `rcS`) and if it exits, the while-loop in `myapp.sh` will start it again.

I verified it worked, but I think this way is alittle ugly, for it shows something in `ps ax` as follows,

```
 1539 root      0:00 {myapp.sh} /bin/sh /etc/init.d/myapp.sh
 1544 root      0:00 /sbin/mdev -df
 1545 root      1:21 myapp
```

I am wondering if there is a clear way to satisfy my requirements for the application?

Comment: I am no help do you have a GitHub page I would like to reproduce with your initrd