# ^C SIGINT does not work in adb shell in Linux

Tags: process, embedded, signals, process-management

I am working on an embedded Linux system, which uses kernel-5.10.24.
It uses busybox as init, and has other utilities in rootfs, including adbd.
I can run `adb shell` from PC to login to the embedded system, then I started a shell script to do something in a loop.

But I found that when I type `^C` to interrupt the script, it failed. I have to use `^Z` first, then `kill -9 xxx` to stop the script running.

When the process is *stopped* by `^Z`, it read its `/proc/pid_of_script/status`, I found followings,

```
SigPnd: 00000000000000000000000000000000
ShdPnd: 00000000000000000000000000020000
SigBlk: 00000000000000000000000000020000
SigIgn: 00000000000000000000000000001006
SigCgt: 00000000000000000000000000020000
```

The SigIgn masked the SIGINT (2). Then I checked its parent process and the grand-parent process (adbd), I found they all ignore SIGINT from their signal processing.

The adbd is started by /etc/init.d/rcS, which calls S50usb (S50usb also calls another script).

Then I changed to start S50usb in /etc/inittab after shell is running. But I got the same result as before.

I wonder if there is a way in run-time to adjust the script process's SigIgn, then SIGINT can stop its running?

Comment: it appears as though SIGQUIT is also ignored.. is your `rcS` possibly launching `adbd` in the background as in `adbd &` ?

Comment: Oops, you are right, the S50usb will start `adbd &`, so that is why SIGINT is ignored, since there is no controll terminal for it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on LL3's comment, and the answer to [What's the difference between running a program as a daemon and forking it into background with '&'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into)I got the solution.
adbd is started by script with `adbd &`, which put it into background.
As a background process, adbd has been set to ignore SIGINT.
The solution might be using `start-stop-daemon` script to launch adbd in the script, instead of using `adbd &` directly.

Comment: Quite correct. Note that _both_ SIGINT _and_ SIGQUIT are ignored. `start-stop-daemon` would make your Ctrl-C work but does not provide auto-respawn. Perhaps you might try and split your app so as to move its initial operations (those that truly need to be run early on) into `rcS` while keeping its long-running operation in `inittab:respawn`. `rcS` (i.e. what lies in `sysinit`) is typically meant to perform _one-off_ bootstrap operations

Comment: You are right on the process life-cycle management, I had another question on it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743389/how-to-start-and-manage-a-process-in-busybox-inittab-and-rcs-as-early-as-possib. Putting process in rcS make it started earlier than in inittab, but lost the respawn property. So I found a way to solve it by starting a wrapper script of long-run process in `rcS` which has a loop to start the real process. It worked fine if the process is running in foreground, but does not work for daemon, welcome any ideas on this.